# Angular *ngFor - Cant get my Arrays to loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, ngfor

This keeps kicking upError: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. But it works when I try print it to the console, any help be appreciated big time guys

Thank you (:

```
//TypeScript File :
public names = ["Jimmy" , "Lilly"];
  public ages = [20,25];
  public profile = {
    Name : this.names,
    Age : this.ages
  }
```

```
//HTML File :
<div *ngFor = "let i of profile">
    {{i.Name}}
    {{i.Age}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error already mentions what's the issue.

> NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

You need to use an array in order that `*ngFor` works

```js
//TypeScript File
public jimmy = { Name: "Jimmy", Age: 20 };
public lilly = { Name: "Lilly", Age: 25 };
public profiles = [jimmy, lilly]
```

```html
//HTML File :
<div *ngFor = "let i of profiles">
    {{i.Name}}
    {{i.Age}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel Yep this worked, I was just confused because it let me printed to the console the other way, but ye makes Sense. Your the Man Daniel (:

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm sure about what you're trying to accomplish, but binding i.Name is incorrect since you defined Name as an array. You could loop over profile.Name using ngFor and then bind the property "name". Changing variable names could be less confusing:)

```
<div *ngFor="let i of profile.Name">
{{i.name}}
</div>
```

Same is applicable for Age

Comment: Sup Johnny ! Yet the reason why I like doing it the other way is because you can have the HTML Display :  
 Lily 25
 Jimmy 20
Instead of  Lily Jimmy 20 25 , Thanks Johnny (: